# Octopus deploy Teamcity deploys an old version

Tags: octopus-deploy

I use teamcity to start a deployment using the octopus plugin.

I have set up a snapsnot dependency.
However the deploy seems to always deploy the same nuget:
0.1.99.

I changed environment name, but can't see that this should be a problem?
**EDIT**
I also did an upgrade from 1.6 to 2.0 for octopus deploy.
When I do a manual deploy I can select the newest package and everything is ok
**Edit 2**
From Teamcity Buildlog
[Octopus Deploy] Steps: 
[12:14:11][Octopus Deploy]   #   Name     Version         Source
[12:14:11][Octopus Deploy]   --- -------- --------------- ------------------------------------
[12:14:11][Octopus Deploy]   1   Deploy   0.1.99          Latest available in NuGet repository

If I look in the nuget feed through the test functionality in the octopus deploy UI, I see that 0.1.153 is available...

Comment: Does your build version increment with every team city build? If so, does the build version that is stamped on the nuget package in the artifacts view in team city not match build version?

Comment: The build version increases with every build and the nuget packages matches...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in one of earlier beta (or RC?) releases of Octopus Deploy 2.0. [It has since been fixed.](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/Issues/issues/422) Basically, it would think that 0.1.99 was a larger (more recent) version number than 0.1.100, similar to the way in math 0.9 > 0.10.

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't understand why this is the solution to the problem, but it is:
I have to specify in a parameter to octopack that it should use a specific version, by using --packageversion

I found the answer here:
http://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/questions/1595-nuget-version-resolution-bug

If someone can explain why octopus can not find the latest version from the nuget feed -that answer will be marked as correct!

Answer (score 0):

Octopus deploys are generally divided in a few steps

1. Create deploy `project-x` version `1.2.3`
2. Deploy `project-x` version `1.2.3` environment `my-environment`

If TeamCity keeps deploying version 0.1.99 from your application my first thought would be that you have hard-coded the version to deploy in your TeamCity configuration.